# Warning: libxml2 is a keg-only and another version is linked to opt

Tags: homebrew, libxml2

When I

```
$ brew install libxml2
```

I get:

> Warning: libxml2 is a keg-only and another version is linked to opt.
>   Use `brew install --force` if you want to install this version

So, is there something wrong here? or just a newer version comes out, I can install that newer version?

I have this warning with:

```
brew install libiconv
```

too.

Comment: Have you ever installed `libxml2` or `libiconv` via a way other than homebrew?

Comment: `brew doctor` may help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
brew install --force libxml2
brew link --force libxml2
```

Comment: This answer worked for me. However, is there any issues with executing this command since it's throwing a "warning'?